# Set UserGroups for existing User

Tags: craft-pro, user-groups

Using Craft::Pro Edition, I want to add a specific UserGroup to an existing User in my module. I tried it this way, but the group is not saved.

```
$userGroup = Craft::$app->userGroups->getGroupByHandle('partner');
$user->setGroups([$userGroup]);
$success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($user);
```

After (successful) saveElement(), $user->getGroups() still returns an empty array.

When I add the group in the Admin CP, it works, but it needs a password confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a user to certain groups via

```
Craft::$app->getUsers()->assignUserToGroups($user->id, [1,2,3]);
```

Would assign them to the groups with the ids 1, 2 and 3